# Haskell stack local install fails after installing GHC

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to install `stack` locally (I am on a university account, and can not make a systemwide install).  I am following the [manual install instructions](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/).  I am on a Red Hat system.

Here is the output from stack:

```
$ ln -s /data/local/ .local
$ ln -s /data/stack/ .stack
$ mv path/to/stack ~/.local/bin/
$ stack install

Writing the configuration file for the implicit global project to:
/data/stack/global-project/stack.yaml. Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field
there.
Using the latest snapshot lts-22.6.
Preparing to install GHC (tinfo6-libc6-pre232) to an isolated location. This will not interfere with
any system-level installation.
Preparing to download ghc-tinfo6-libc6-pre232-9.6.3 ...
ghc-tinfo6-libc6-pre232-9.6.3: download has begun
ghc-tinfo6-libc6-pre232-9.6.3:   93.91 MiB / 192.42 MiB ( 48.80%) downloaded...
ghc-tinfo6-libc6-pre232-9.6.3:  192.42 MiB / 192.42 MiB (100.00%) downloaded...
Downloaded ghc-tinfo6-libc6-pre232-9.6.3.
Unpacking GHC into /data/stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-libc6-pre232-9.6.3.temp/ ...
Configuring GHC ...
/data/stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-libc6-pre232-9.6.3.temp/ghc-9.6.3-x86_64-unknown-linux/configure: line 6576: FP_PROG_LD_BUILD_ID: command not found
ar: conftest.a: No such file or directory
Installing GHC ...
Installed GHC.

Error: [S-8506]
       Stack failed to parse the target(s).
       
       While parsing, Stack encountered the error:
       
           The specified targets matched no packages. Perhaps you need to run stack init?
       
       Stack expects a target to be a package name (e.g. my-package), a package identifier (e.g.
       my-package-0.1.2.3), a package component (e.g. my-package:test:my-test-suite), or, failing
       that, a relative path to a directory that is a local package directory or a parent directory
       of one or more local package directories.
```

How can I overcome this?  My ultimate goal is to be able to use this installation to have access to a recent GHC and install packages that can be used by any project.

Note that I am using the `/data` directory because my account has a quota and `stack`'s install is unbelievably huge.  I intend to move it to my home directory after I've gotten rid of all of the unnecessary garbage, as `/data` is a temporary directory.  In addition to the above error, will I have to rewrite a bunch of files to refer to `~/.stack` and `~/.local` instead of `/data/stack` and `/data/local`?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ghcup](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/install/) to install Haskell, Stack and Cabal. Are you able to install ghcup? I am not sure if that is a system wide installation or not.